# linux: how many files in dir?

Tags: directory

I want an output similar to this,to show how many files and eventually subdirs are contained in directories.
The output can be similar to this one

```
dir1 100
dir2/dir3 240
dir3 12
dir5 44
...
```

Which app,script can make this?

Comment: What about subdirectories?

Comment: Forgot..and subdirs too.Edited now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have GNU find, you can do:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -printf "%h\n" | uniq -c
```

For example:

```
$ find /etc/skel /etc/profile.d /etc/resolvconf -type f -printf "%h\n" | uniq -c 
     10 /etc/profile.d
      1 /etc/resolvconf
      2 /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d
      1 /etc/resolvconf/update.d
      1 /etc/resolvconf/update-libc.d
      6 /etc/skel
```

`%h` prints the directory name of the matched file, so, after that it's a simple matter of getting `uniq` to count the number of times the foldername was duplicated.

Comment: find works recursively, so it will display how many files are contained in the /path/to/directory directory as well as all its directories.

Comment: @Georgi yes, that's right. But no file will be counted more then once.

Comment: @GeorgiTsvetanovTsenov yes, but here, for each file it's only printing its immediate parent directory, so the count given for each directory is only for files in it, not in subdirectories. But subdirectories are recursively listed.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution

```
du -a | cut -d/ -f2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

From this [site](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-find-the-total-number-of-files-in-a-folder-510009/)

Output is

```
 31 dir2
  2 dir3
  1 dir4
```

Answer (score 1):

This will count files in directories for you starting at `.`. You can provide a starting path to the first `find` if you want:

```
find -type d -exec bash -c 'printf "%s %d\n" "{}" $(find "{}" -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l)' \;
```

It works by descending the tree of directories (from `.` or from an explicit path that you might provide) and calling the `bash -c '...'` snippet for each. This snippet prints the directory pathname and the the number of files it contains.

Here's sample output from `/etc`

```
/etc 27
/etc/alternatives 1
/etc/bash_completion.d 6
/etc/dbus-1 2
/etc/defaults 0
/etc/defaults/etc 16
/etc/defaults/etc/freetds 3
/etc/defaults/etc/inetd.d 1
/etc/defaults/etc/my.cnf.d 4
/etc/defaults/etc/pki 0
/etc/defaults/etc/pki/ca-trust 1
/etc/defaults/etc/profile.d 5
...
```